# Some tables give 'new row violates row-level security policy' error but some do not

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security, retool

I have created a new login role and assigned permissions to it:

```
CREATE ROLE myuser
LOGIN
PASSWORD 'password';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON customer TO myuser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON campaign TO myuser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON lead TO myuser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON lead_history TO myuser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON log TO myuser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON stats TO myuser;
```

When I log in to that role, I can now do any operation with the customer table, but if I try action queries with the other tables I get a 'new row violates row-level security policy for table "campaign"' error. If I do a select, no results are returned.

I checked the information_schema.table_privileges table and all of the permissions are the same for the tables.

Why would doing the exact same thing have different results on different tables?

I am using Supabase on the backend and Retool on the front end.

I cannot find any row level security policies for either table in `pg_policy`. In fact the whole `pg_policy` table appears empty. If I head over to Supabase's Policies page, all tables have RLS enabled.

Comment: There are row level security (RLS) policies on those tables. Run `SELECT * FROM pg_policy WHERE polrelid = 'public.campaign'::regclass;` to confirm this. RLS policies are not reflected in `information_schema`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a table has row level security enabled, but there is no row level security policy, everything is forbidden by default: you can see none of the rows, and inserting rows will cause the error you observe. This applies to all users subject to row level security (exceptions are superusers, the table owner and users defined with `BYPASSRLS`).

Disable row level security:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

Comment: Hmmm. I want to keep RLS as I will be using that as some point, so I add some generic RLS policy for now I guess. But how come it works with that one table that as far as I can tell has all of the same properties as the others?

Comment: Perhaps you own that table?

Comment: No, they were created by my boss using the postgres user. I added the new myuser role and assigned exactly as you see above and logged in to that user.  Maybe he did did something different when creating the `customer` table that is having downstream effects. But I do not know how to look for that at this point.

Comment: Connect with `psql` and run `\d+ tablename` and `\dt+ tablename`. That will show you. Compare the differences.

Comment: Yup, customer did not have RLS and the others did. Boss man did something different when creating that table.